# How could be HTML markup working in Safari and not working in Chrome

Tags: html, safari, google-chrome

The problem is on my blog - blog.dynback.com.

Right panel goes down in Chrome, and stayed normal in all other browsers including Safari 4. And without Firebug its hard to find where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has do to with the JavaScript. I've noticed the issue appears after code snippets are highlighted. Chrome uses a different JavaScript engine than Safari. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I changed highlighter, that is js library, and it works. Or it doesnot tested on Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately, now is not working on Firefox 3 and Opera 9.6 but hey, IE6 looks great :)

Answer (score 3):

You have errors in your markup, fix those first, at least the missing end-tags.

Validate here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.dynback.com

Comment: Jeff: Even less fun when you try to wrap them around a I <3 validator-image! Strangly enough the preview looked very very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to shrink the width of #main_content